# 'An error occurred while trying to authenticate: Failed to validate signature.' While using `oauth-1.0a` and nodejs

Tags: node.js, xml, http, oauth, node-request

I'm getting this odd error in nodejs when I try to send a post request with `oauth-1.0a` and node.js.

Request:

```
Headers:
Authorization: OAuth <...>
Accept: 'application/xml',
Content-Type: 'application/xml'

Body:
<account>
    <firstName>${first}</firstName>
    <lastName>${last}</lastName>
    <email>${email}</email>
    <urlRedirect>${redirecturl}</urlRedirect>
</account>`
```

Response:

```
401
An error occurred while trying to authenticate: Failed to validate signature.
```

Code:

```js
require('dotenv').config()
const request = require('request')
const OAuth = require('oauth-1.0a')
const crypto = require('crypto')
var first = "real";
var last = "person";
var email = "real@person.com";
var redirecturl = "http://google.com"
const oauth = OAuth({
    version: '1.0a',
    consumer: {
        key: process.env.CONSUMERKEY,
        secret: process.env.CONSUMERSECRET,
    },
    signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
    hash_function(base_string, key) {
        return crypto
            .createHmac('sha1', key)
            .update(base_string)
            .digest('base64')
    },
})
console.log(oauth)
const token = {
    key: process.env.KEY,
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
}
const request_data = {
    url: `https://${process.env.CHURCHCODE}.fellowshiponeapi.com/v1/Accounts`,
    method: 'POST',
    data: `<account>
    <firstName>${first}</firstName>
    <lastName>${last}</lastName>
    <email>${email}</email>
    <urlRedirect>${redirecturl}</urlRedirect>
  </account>`
}
const headers = Object.assign( oauth.toHeader(oauth.authorize(request_data, token)), {
    Accept: 'application/xml',
    'Content-Type': 'application/xml'
});
console.log(headers); 
request(
    {
        url: request_data.url,
        method: request_data.method,
        headers: headers
    },
    function(error, response, body) {
        console.log(response.statusCode)
        console.log(response.statusMessage)
     }
)
```

Why is this error occurring?

Edit: one of the more useful resources I used was this: https://oauth.net/core/1.0/#signing_process but I still can't figure this out.

Should also mention that this request does work, as in postman it successfully goes through.

Answer (score 0):

You typically want to provide the token in a request using this header:

```
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

Not

```
Authorization: OAuth <...>
```

Comment: I'm using OAuth, how would I do this? Everywhere I've seen says use this format for OAuth 1.0a: `OAuth oauth_consumer_key="consumerkey", oauth_nonce="nonce", oauth_signature="signature", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="timestamp", oauth_token="token", oauth_version="1.0a"` - also, the F1 api is very picky, so I'm not sure this would work. (https://developer.fellowshipone.com)

Comment: I get this error using this: ```401
An error occurred while trying to authenticate: Must include valid access token to authenticate```

+ I'm using a token and a secret together, do I combine them?

Comment: why are you using  oauth-1.0a? and what target authentication service are you trying to authenticate to?  OAuth 1.0 is not a recommended protocol to use today.